# Batch class not getting field value in execute method?

Tags: apex, batch

I wrote a batch with the query

```
start{
QueryLocator('SELECT ID,JOB_Code__c from user where IsActive = true')
       //I can see the query in debug log
    }
execute(List<sobject> scope )
{
   system.debug(Scope) ;//This is returning only ID of the user not the job code.
}
```

I try to execute the batch in service console.

```
Database.executeBatch(bc,20);
```

I checked the FLS for the field job_code__c . its given access to admin. Any advice..

didn't get any trace...

//Base on answer below , I see no records but

Expected debug log should be

> (User:{Id=005320000052J1qAAE,Job_Code__c = null }, User:{Id=005320000052J1sAAE,Job_Code__c = null },

but actual

> (User:{Id=005320000052J1qAAE}, User:{Id=005320000052J1sAAE},

I am using the getOfvalue in execute process.So there i got null error, I can put null pointer check but still the above is unclear.

```
string jobcode = userObj.get(Job_Code_c) //This gives null pointer exception.
```

Comment: Is there any error? Try to query the same scope query in workbench and see if there is any records populated with the JOB_Code__c

Comment: Yes. My mistake..I see no record values. Thank you.

Comment: Please mark the below answer to resolve the question

Answer (score 1):

Is there any error? Try to query the same scope query in workbench and see if there is any records populated with the JOB_Code__c

Question resolved in comments.

Comment: Yes. But one query ..If i see the scope it should show something like this in debug right (User:{Id=005320000052J1qAAE,Job_code__c = null}, User:{Id=005320000052J1sAAE,,Job_code__c = null},...   but actually i got this (User:{Id=005320000052J1qAAE}, User:{Id=005320000052J1sAAE},..

Comment: No, it will not show the column if the value is not populated